# Fantasy paperback about a sorceress/witch that could turn her minions into wolves

Tags: story-identification, books

This would have been a book I found in the early 2000's.

I don't remember much about it other than there was a sorceress/witch that could turn her minions into wolves.

The cover had a stone castle, with the witch in a red dress standing in the doorway, and her two soldiers in front and off to the side, carrying swords and wearing fur/leather armor.

Comment: This question is quite terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, what was the name of the sorceress? Was she the main character or the villain? How did she turn her minions into wolves (giving them a potion, casting a spell)? Did she have some sort of magical tools (staff/gem/whatever)? Why did she want her minions to be wolves? Did they stay wolves afterwards? Did the wolves attack anyone? Were they any other characters? What were their names? Were they explicitly referred to as "wolves" or another word (manwolf, werewolves, etc)?